# mongo command not found after installing in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have run the following commands, and then was able to successfully login to `mongo` root (as shown in the image). When I typed `mongo` I get the following error. Why is this and how can I solve it?

> bash: mongo command not found

```
Docker run -d -p 27017:27017  --name shopping-mongo mongo
Docker logs -f shopping-mongo
Docker exec -it shopping-mongo /bin/bash
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `mongosh`? Mongo is not supported in the newer versions

Comment: There's a version from rtps and gianni. Which one should I use ?